# Can I detect when a Windows process starts up without writing system level code?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, process, monitoring

Is there any way by means of performance monitoring, WMI, or other freely available tools, to detect when a specific process is started, or even better, is about to be started? Then, further, to capture the command line parameters passed to the entry point function for that process.

Merely detecting that the process has at some time been started and is already running is of no value for my requirement. I have Visual Studio starting up Chrome for a debugging session, and I would like to a) find out if VS uses cmd.exe to start Chrome, or some code internal to VS, and b) what parameters VS passes to Chrome to configure it for integrated debugging.

Or is there maybe some way I can use PowerShell to place some kind of watch on the process image, i.e. the .exe file, to see when it is accessed for execution?

Answer (score 5):

You'd want to watch the process that STARTS the process, and not just the target process itself, most likely.

[**Process Monitor**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) by SysInternals should be able to capture this.

Filter for the Visual Studio process (and possibly also for CMD and Chrome), trigger the debug sequence in VS, and see what is captured.

Another option, also from SysInternals, would be [**Process Explorer**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), basically Task Manager on steroids, which captures the arguments that started each process. If VS starts an intermediary which then opens Chrome AND that intermediary remains running as a parent of the Chrome process, Process Explorer will show you any arguments passed.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I've been casually using PE instead of Task Manager for years, and never known or notices that it can show me arguments passed.

Comment: Hovering your mouse over a process shows you the full argument path. It's quite handy.